# C# - Asynchronous event firing during I/O card reading

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'am creating a wrapper for an I/O card. I have a DLL library for accessing the I/O card. Currently, my class is using this DLL to open the card, and to read / write it's channels.
I'am using a while loop to continuously read the output ports, something like this:

```
while (_enabled)
{
    BitArray _currentState = ReadCurrentDiValue(); // read DI data with DLL
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        if (_cardState[i] != _currentState[i])
        {
            _cardState[i] = _currentState[i];

            OnBitChanged(new BitChangedEventArgs()
            {
                Port = (byte)i,
                Value = _currentState[i]
            }); // I want to fire this event asynchronously 
        }
    }
}
```

This loop is running on a separated thread. My problem is that, the event listener can potentially block this thread from running, by doing any hard work in the event handler. In this case, maybe an incoming physical signal to the I/O card won't be recognized.
The question is, what is the correct way to solve this problem?
I have two ideas.
The first is to simply fire the event using Task.Run:

```
Task.Run(() => {
    OnBitChanged(new BitChangedEventArgs()
    {
        Port = (byte)i,
        Value = _currentState[i]
    }); 
});
```

The second approach is to call the BeginInvoke on the delegate, inside the OnBitChanged method:

```
if (BitChanged != null)
{
    var listeners = BitChanged.GetInvocationList();
    foreach (var listener in listeners)
    {
        var eventHandler = (EventHandler) listener;
        eventHandler.BeginInvoke(this, eventargs, ar =>
        {
            try
            {
                eventHandler.EndInvoke(ar);
            }
            catch
            {
                // ignore
            }
        }, null);
    }
}
```

Any other ideas? Am I on a totally wrong path?

Comment: Will this be a library which might be used by someone who might block in the event handler, or will you use it internally with full controll over the actual event handlers?

Comment: Don't get your network layers confused.You have a data layer (the ports) and an App Layer.You have multiple threads (app layer) sharing the same data layer.  You have a master(client)/Slave(server/listener) the app layer.So the client is sending a command, the server processes command, then send back a response.So the solution is to send one command and wait for response before sending next command.  You have a parallel threads sending commands(getting responses) the solution is to create a message queue.Then add an ID to each message/response and keep track of which thread send which message.

Comment: Mostly I'll use it, but also others can use it in their projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two are almost identical - both will post the handler to the thread pool. So you're better off with the `Task.Run`, which has a nicer interface.

The approach that is used the most commonly is to use a queue of some sort. This way, you're not wasting more threads than necessary. This may be as simple as having another thread read from the queue and executing the handlers, or a custom task scheduler that you can use with `Task.Run`. The threadpool itself is also a queue, but it introduces parallelism to the handlers, which might be undesirable - I expect that your application protocol expects to work in a single thread of execution.

Finally, if not reading the data can cause a data loss, you still have an opportunity to lose data even if you post the handler to another thread - ultimately, you need an API that can buffer on its own.